# Empty razor page check if id exist

Tags: c#, database, razor

For my own project i want to be able to delete tip articles, this works. but know i have the problem that it also deletes tip articles that don't exist. does someone know how to fix this?

code in the tip article manager:

```
 *//Delete tip article in db
        public bool DeleteTipArticle(int articleNumber)
        {
                FillTipArticleList();
                return tipArticleDB.DeleteDb(articleNumber);          
        }*
```

code in the database:

```
//Delete the tip article for the tiparticle database
        public bool DeleteDb(int articleNumber)
        {
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(databaseConnection);

            //Sql string for deleting the tip article
            string sql = "DELETE FROM tiparticle WHERE ArticleNumber = @ArticleNumber";

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArticleNumber", articleNumber);

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                int amount = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return amount > 0;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
            catch (FormatException ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

code behind the razor page:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    public class DeleteTipArticleModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public int articleNumber { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string message = "The tip article has been deleted!";
                ViewData["Message"] = message;

                TipArticleManager deleteToTipArticleDatabase = new TipArticleManager();
                deleteToTipArticleDatabase.DeleteTipArticle(articleNumber);

                return Page();
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["Message"] = "Please enter all data fields";
                return Page();
            }
        }
    }
```

i think that i have to do something with the amount > 0 that gets returned, but i am not sure where and how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the return value of `bool succeeded = deleteToTipArticleDatabase.DeleteTipArticle(articleNumber);` to check for amount > 0.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public class DeleteTipArticleModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public int articleNumber { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            TipArticleManager deleteToTipArticleDatabase = new TipArticleManager();
            bool succeeded =   DeleteToTipArticleDatabase.DeleteTipArticle(articleNumber);
            if(succeeded)
            {         
                 string message = "The tip article has been deleted!";
                 ViewData["Message"] = message;
            }
            return Page();
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Please enter all data fields";
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise you could make a database call for the article number to see if it is already present.

Comment: do i have to put this in the article manager or? and what would the database call to get the article number?

Comment: You are already proceeding the return value in the article manager. So it should work if you put it in the OnPost() function of the DeleteTipArticleModel.

Comment: could you maybe show me how it will look like with the checking, i really don't know how to check if the amount > 0

Comment: I modified my answer.

Comment: i implemented the code, but i still get a message when article number 55 is deleted (which doesn't exist in my database). the message says: The article has been removed succesfully)

Comment: I modified the answer. Now the message should only show up if amount > 0.

Comment: yes it works now, thank you so much! my only question is how the bool succeeded works

Comment: No problem! Your function DeleteTipArticle(articleNumber) returns a bool, which contains "amount > 0". If an element is deleted then amount > 0 is true. This is saved in the succeeded variable, which will be checked in the if statement and if true, it returns the message.